# Cancel an HttpClient request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am making a simple request for a file using HttpClient from the Apache Commons. Here is my current code:

```
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpget = new HttpGet(location);
    context = new BasicHttpContext();
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);
    entity = response.getEntity();
```

What would I need to do to cancel this request in the middle of the download?

Comment: If the request is so simple, what do you need Apache commons for?

Comment: +1 on @Thomas's comment. Why not just use `java.net`? Then you can easily close the stream anytime you want.

Comment: Well...its currently simple, with the likelihood to become much more complex. I'll be adding in several custom HTTP headers in a little while.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `httpget.abort()` method to abort the request mid way.

See example [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAbortMethod.java)

Comment: Great thanks, couldn't find that in the docs for some reason.

Comment: This may not be the intended solution. It appears to only bypass reading the response object. What if I want to **abort before response** is received.