# It is possible to stop a thread that is connecting to URL with httpConnection.connect()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, urlconnection, httpconnection

i have a thread that is connecting to a url to obtaining some data.

Sometimes the method `httpConnection.connect();` taked too munch time to get the response, and i want to limit the loading dialog of this connection thread to 5 seg.

I tryed adding timeouts into the code, **but it doesn't work**!!

```
URL formattedUrl = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection connection = formattedUrl.openConnection(); 
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            httpConnection.connect();
```

So, i must stop the connect method and the thread when 5000 seconds have passed or when the used has pressed the back key on the phone.

How can this be achieved? i can't find info about doing this work in android with a url connection thread.

thanks

Comment: The problem here is not how to stop the thread, it is why the timeouts don't work. NB you don't need to set them twice. The connection and httpConnection objects are still the same object.

Comment: i tryed all with the timeouts and didn't work properly, i must to stop the thread also when the user press back key, so i need to learn the way to achieve this

Comment: No, you must get the timeouts working. Are you really seeing connect() execute for more than five seconds? Or is it the combination of connect() and read()? What is really happening here?

Comment: The bigger problem here is that you don't want to "just kill" the thread.  It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

The timeout settings on URLConnection are not sufficient to provide the timeout control desired.  The reason being is:

- setConnectTimeout() sets the timeout for just establishing a connection with the server.  So, a timeout will only be triggered if when opening the connection, the connection can not be established in the prescribed amount of time.
- setReadTimeount() sets the timeout for reading available data.  For this, a timeout will only be triggered if any, **single** read operation blocks for longer than the set amount of time.  So, it is quite possible even on a slow connection that each read operation never approaches the timeout threshold but, the total amount of time to read all the data is quite lengthly.

One solution to apply a timeout to the entire read unit of work, is to use the concurrency capabilities found in Java 5 and beyond.  In particular, the use of an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) should be sufficient.

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // original code to read data from a URL
    }
};

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  // or any other implementation
Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
try {
    future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait 5 seconds for task to complete
    // success
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // handle timeout
} finally {
    executor.shutdownNow(); // cleanup
}
```

Comment: Sorry ahead of time for the noob question...Isn't running `future.get()` defeating the purpose of running your code in the background? `future.get` is supposed to block its current thread, which will probably be the main thread.

Comment: @JeremyJao, you are correct in asserting `get` is a blocking call.  The original question relates to how to abort a download if it is taking to long.  That is what the above is trying to accomplish by executing a background task and waiting for it to complete up to the prescribed time.  If the blocking of the calling thread is an issue, then the above would also need to be executed on a separate thread somehow.  I did not sense the blocking of the calling thread was the crux of the original question, so I did not address it with my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Brent Worden's answer is on the right track.  But there is a problem with his solution.  If the task timeout kicks in, the thread that called `future.get` will get an exception as expected.  However, the worker thread that was executing the `Runnable.run()` method *may* still be stuck waiting for the connect or read to complete.

Solving this is difficult.  As far as I'm aware, the only reliable way to unjam a thread that is waiting on a socket connect or socket stream read or write is to call `close()` on the `Socket` object.  And the problem with using that approach (here) is that the standard `HttpUrlConnection` object doesn't expose the `Socket` object.

My recommendation would be to use the Apache Http client libraries.  This question explains how to abort a request if you use HttpClient: [Cancel an HttpClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400258/cancel-an-httpclient-request)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to invoke the [URLConnection.setConnectTimeout(millis)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) to achieve what you asking. If the specified timeout expires a [SocketTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) is thrown.

```
try {
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
   con.setConnectTimeout(5000); //set timeout to 5 seconds
} catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
   //DO SOMETHING
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

It's worth noting that it says the following:

> Some non-standard implmentation of this method may ignore the
>   specified timeout. To see the connect timeout set, please call
>   getConnectTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the process which the thread belongs to will end if you stop the thread.